# Filter based on decrypted value using DecryptByKey

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption

I have the following simplified query which should filter the decrypted column values

```
SELECT ResourceId, ClientId, UserName
FROM dbo.Resources
WHERE DecrpytByKey(UserName) LIKE '%PETER%';
```

It doesn't work and returns me 0 results

If I use

```
SELECT  K.ResourceId, K.ClientId, K.DUserName
FROM (
    SELECT ResourceId, ClientId, UserName, DecrpytByKey(UserName) AS DUserName
    FROM dbo.Resources
) AS K 
WHERE K.DUserName LIKE '%PETER%'
```

This works correctly and gives me the desired results.

I want to go with something similar to option #1, since I want it to be efficient and filter the results before the join.

Is there a way to filter based on the decrypted value in the same select statement?

Comment: edited to add table alias

Comment: While I can understand you wanting to know why its not working, I think you will find that both queries are equally effective. How a query is written is not how SQL Server executes it, and generally its pretty good at optimising.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Please share query plans of both queries via https://pastetheplan.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but your queries are doing exactly the same thing. Both of them are doing full scan on table so performance will be same.

Unfortunately, %% in this case are making performance fix impossible.